# How to program datawedge on mc67 to advance to next screen after scanning a barcode

Tags: barcode-scanner, datawedge

I am currently trying to configure datawedge on a Motorola MC67. It works fine when scanning a barcode to an open field in the application that I am using for our WMS software. However if there is no open field, nothing happens when scanning the barcode. Can datawedge be configured to advance to the next screen when there is no open field in which to scan?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to append characters like tab and enter to the end of a barcode so typically you would use characters like these to advance to the next screen.  Please take a look at the 'Basic Format Examples' or 'Basic Format Process Plug-in Configuration' pages of the help file.  Note the help file for DW for WM/CE is available from the desktop installation (zip) for DataWedge available from https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/utilities/datawedge-toolkit.html.